# How to cache database that used by dblookup mediator

Tags: caching, wso2, wso2-esb

I am going to take some details from mysql tables into esb using db-lookup mediator and it works perfectly without any problem. But since it accessing databases, it will impact the performance. So I want to cache some data from database and read from cache instead of directly reading from database. I found a mediator called cache mediator which related to caching. But not clear how to use it with my scenario. Is it possible? If its possible, Can anyone show me an example code on how to implement it.

This is the way I use dblookup mediator.

```
<dblookup>
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <password>password</password>
            <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb</url>
            <user>root</user>
        </pool>
    </connection>
    <statement>
        <sql><![CDATA[select * from user limit 1]]></sql>
        <result column="username" name="user"/>
    </statement>
</dblookup>
```

I just want to get the result from cache instead of database.

Comment: Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565969/how-to-reserve-property-value-between-every-task-call/36566342#36566342

Answer (score 0):

The caching mediator is used to cache responses of EI so depending on your usecase you can use this to increase performance, but it cannot be used for dblookup.

First I would advise you to evaluate the performance, it should be quite fast already. You could try to configure a datasource (either in 'masterdatasources.xml' or through the carbon GUI) and use in your proxy the following to refer to the datasource

```
<dblookup>
   <connection>
      <pool>
        <dsName>yourdatasourcename</dsName>
      </pool>
   </connection>
   <statement>
      <sql><![CDATA[select * from user limit 1]]></sql>
      <result column="username" name="user"/>
   </statement>
</dblookup>
```